# How can I use elseif to fix my code?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have this Excel VBA code that should tell me which sum to pay based on the product, but wether I type "credit" or any other product it skips the first IF statement and gets to the second one.

I'd like to know how I can use else if so it will genarate the right sum.

Here is the code:

```
Dim prod As String
Dim sumam As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim rate As Integer

prod = InputBox("Introduceti tipul de produs")
total = InputBox("Introduceti suma totala de plata")

If prod = credit Then
   If total < 1000 Then sumam = 175
   If total > 1000 And total < 3000 Then sumam = 350
   If total > 3000 And total < 6000 Then sumam = 425
Else
   If total < 1000 Then sumam = 150
   If total > 1000 And total < 2000 Then sumam = 200
   If total > 2000 And total < 5000 Then sumam = 325
   If total > 5000 And total < 8000 Then sumam = 450
   If total > 8000 And total < 12000 Then sumam = 550
   If total > 12000 Then sumam = 675
rate = total / sumam

textprod.Text = prod
textprod.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
texttot.Text = total
texttot.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
textsumm.Text = sumam
textsumm.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
textrate.Text = rate
textrate.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.  That will point you directly to errors like this.

Comment: Looking at the comments, we can't understand why prod doesn't show as credit, could you add a line Debug.Print "'" & prod & "'" after the input box and then let us know what the result in the immediate window is.

Answer (score 1):

[Untested]

Hi Putaru, try including double quotes on credit. Like this:

```
If prod = "credit" Then
   If total < 1000 Then sumam = 175
   If total > 1000 And total < 3000 Then sumam = 350
   If total > 3000 And total < 6000 Then sumam = 425
   Else...
```

I'm not sure what textprod is? Not sure if that's an object or not, but adding in double quotes should let that if statement check a value, and not a variable called credit, and instead it will check for a string named "credit" with the double quotes included in the code.

Hope this works, as I said, this is untested...

Because the way you have it like this:

```
If prod = credit Then
   If total < 1000 Then sumam = 175
   If total > 1000 And total < 3000 Then sumam = 350
   If total > 3000 And total < 6000 Then sumam = 425
Else
```

And it's looking for a variable called credit, which you don't declare.
Happy coding :)

EDIT:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim prod As String
Dim sumam As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim rate As Integer

prod = InputBox("Enter credit or cheque")
total = InputBox("Enter total")
sumam = 0
rate = 0

If prod = "credit" Then
   If total < 1000 Then sumam = 175
   If total > 1000 And total < 3000 Then sumam = 350
   If total > 3000 And total < 6000 Then sumam = 425
Else
   If total < 1000 Then sumam = 150
   If total > 1000 And total < 2000 Then sumam = 200
   If total > 2000 And total < 5000 Then sumam = 325
   If total > 5000 And total < 8000 Then sumam = 450
   If total > 8000 And total < 12000 Then sumam = 550
   If total > 12000 Then sumam = 675
End If
rate = total / sumam
MsgBox (rate)
End Sub
```

Tested this, and it doesn't return 0 anymore, it will display in a message box, your value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing double quotes... You should use prod = "credit" instead of prod = credit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this;

```
If prod = "credit" Then
```

Note the quotes around the word credit.

Comment: Hi! If I do this it doesn't return anything, I probably should have mentioned this before :P.

Comment: That's strange, it goes through the procedure for me up to this line; textprod.Text = prod - then it fails because of an object error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ElseIf` is another way to do what you are doing but it doesn't have to be the fix. Below is an `ElseIf` Example: -

```
Public Sub ElseIfSample()

If total < 1000 Then
    sumam = 175
ElseIf total > 1000 And total < 3000 Then
    sumam = 350
ElseIf total > 3000 And total < 6000 Then
    sumam = 425
End If

End Sub
```

But this and your previous code will both have the same issue of missing values 1000, 3000, and anything over 5999

The below code would fix that along with some other small changes: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim LngSumam    As Long
Dim LngRate     As Long
Dim StrProd     As String
Dim StrTotal    As String

StrProd = InputBox("Introduceti tipul de produs")
StrTotal = InputBox("Introduceti suma totala de plata")

If Not IsNumeric(StrTotal) Then Exit Sub

If Trim(UCase(StrProd)) = "CREDIT" Then
    If CLng(StrTotal) >= 3000 Then       'Total equal to or above 3000
        LngSumam = 425
    ElseIf CLng(StrTotal) >= 1000 Then   'Total equal to or above 1000
        LngSumam = 350
    Else                                'All other cases
        LngSumam = 175
    End If
Else
    If CLng(StrTotal) >= 12000 Then       'Total equal to or above 12000
        LngSumam = 675
    ElseIf CLng(StrTotal) >= 8000 Then   'Total equal to or above 8000
        LngSumam = 550
    ElseIf CLng(StrTotal) >= 5000 Then   'Total equal to or above 5000
        LngSumam = 550
    ElseIf CLng(StrTotal) >= 2000 Then   'Total equal to or above 2000
        LngSumam = 325
    ElseIf CLng(StrTotal) >= 1000 Then   'Total equal to or above 1000
        LngSumam = 200
    Else                                'All other cases
        LngSumam = 200
    End If

LngRate = CLng(StrTotal) / LngSumam

textprod.Text = StrProd
textprod.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
texttot.Text = StrTotal
texttot.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
textsumm.Text = LngSumam
textsumm.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
textrate.Text = LngRate
textrate.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight

End If

End Sub
```

- Used `Long` instead of `Integer` as `Long` handles bigger numbers easier,
- Changed the input variables to `String` to ensure less errors

You could have also used nested `If` statements or `Select Case`.

NOTE: The text fields in your cod only get filled in if the user doesn't enter 'Credit' in the first input box, is this correct?

Comment: It still skips if I write "CREDIT". As for the note: yes, but now when I write credit it skips the credit options and returns the ones from else.

Comment: Hmm, that is a different problem I think as it does work for me. In the first message box you type "credit" (without the apostrophes') and yes it doesn't go into that section?

Comment: No, it returns the values from the second section.

Comment: I think this question is answered but you now have a new one you should start as it does work for me and the only way we can understand why its not working for you is to see the code itself in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The common cause for this are trims, mix of U/lcase (Since it's an input for the user he may have type as he feels to). Have you tried?:

```
If lcase(Trim(prod)) = "credit" Then
```

Comment: Still, what happens if he has "CRedit, CREDIT, etc" ?